# Glassfish can't find my application path correctly?

Tags: deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3, web-deployment, production-environment

I always developed on `Glassfish`, using the deploy feature on it, but it seems that on productio is a little different, it seems that can't find my application path correclty.
I have this domain [brainset.com.br](http://brainset.com.br/), which you can see this screen when clicking on the link:
[image]

I didn't configure this `Glassfish` before, 'cause I don't know how to do it.
The website it's on air (or it should be) and I need to setup glassfish to the correct path.

```
brainset.com.br // gives the screen above
brainset.com.br/BRAINSET // it's the correct page, my index.xhtml
```

What I'm missing here ? Sorry if my post lack any information, I will provide soon as demanded, 'cause I don't know what could be useful to the post tough.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution, don't know if is the most correct one, but it works.
I had to acess my hosting account and navigate through the folders to found out where glassfish was installed, so inside `/glassfish/domains/domain/docroot` I edited this way the `index.html` file, then upload back the index.html overwriting it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.brainset.com.br/BRAINSET">
  </head>
</html>
```

I think this is not the most correct way, 'cause I think that `Glassfish` can contain many different applications inside of it, which itself can handle the requests and redirect to the correct application and this way it always go to the same application, but I could be wrong on this. :)